# How to properly pass environmental variable in Docker to Spring application as run argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a problem where I'm trying to pass environmental variable in Docker as command line argument for Spring, but not via `-Drun.arguments`, but as normal command line argument because I need it in class that implements `CommandLineRunner` and because as I read somewhere `CommandLineRunner` only takes arguments that are written after your application `.jar` file in command line, i.e. `java -jar app.jar commandlineargument`.

In docker file I have this:

```
ENV SPRING_PROFILE="" \
    JAVA_ARGS0=""

CMD ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILE}","app.jar","--${JAVA_ARGS0}"]
```

When app starts it successfully reads the variable `SPRING_PROFILE` and it starts with profile I put in configmap, but when I print my arguments in class that implements `CommandLineRunner`, value of the argument is string `${JAVA_ARGS0}` instead of value from the variable.

I checked if the value is set for `JAVA_ARGS0` and it is, so I'm wondering how am I supposed to pass the value.

Comment: Use a plain string, not a JSON array; `CMD java -jar app.jar --${JAVA_ARGS0}`.

Comment: In a Spring context, also consider that Spring can read properties from environment variables, so setting `ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=...` might be easier than using a command-line argument.  Depending on how the additional arguments are being used, passing them via environment variables might be easier than using positional arguments.